# What is the best RESTful uri for a resource's tags

Tags: rest, uri

Say you have a resource of recipes and a recipe can have tags.  Then you want to get a list of all tags used across all recipes, what would the URI be?

```
/recipes/tags
```

Seems like it might work but it breaks the convention of not pointing to a specific id such as:

```
/recipes/1/tags
```

You could also just use:

```
/tags
```

But I only want tags for recipes not any other resource.  So would I use query params, such as:

```
/tags?type-recipes
```

And FTR, tags are only used for recipes not any other resource, so it seems misleading to use the query param since it would never be anything but recipes

Comment: the first one is the best way, you don't need to point to a specific id, just point to a resource.

Answer (score 1):

Filters are tricky -- especially when your filter is also a resource.

You are correct that /recipes/tags is problematic.  You go from a path variable of /resouce/{resouceId} to /resource/{filter} which can open a whole word of pain.

So for your first example go for something like

```
 /recipes?tags={tags to filter on}
 Returns a list of Recipes based on the tag
```

The problem is you don't have any lookup method for what acceptable tags are. I would expect /tags to return a list of tags and then consume it like this

```
 /tags
 Returns a list of all tags

 /tags/{tagID}
 Returns meta data about the specific tag (what the tag is used for, which is superfluous in this case if you only have recipe tags, but it is more flexible)

 /tags/{tagID}/recipes
 Returns a list of recipes associated with that ID.
```

Then you have to decide if you want to support a linked resource like this

```
 /tags/eggs/recipes/1
 Recipe details
```

Which would still be the same thing as

```
/recipes/1
```

It's acceptable to link them -- just might get confusing if recipe/2 doesn't have any eggs in it and you try to access it using /tags/eggs/recipes/2